# How to use, change and return variables/lists in functions called by tkinter buttons?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Im working on a Prgogramm with an GUI which stores, manipulate and analizes some Data. The data is stored in a json file like:

```
dict = {"team1_id":{"id1":id1,"id2":id2,"name":name},"team2_id":{"id1":id1,"id2":id2,"name":name}}
```

I have several functions which works with that data. For easier work i load the Data into 4 lists (internal_id_list,id1_list,id2_list,name_list) where each indice is pointing at the same  team.
Currently i open and load the data in every function new. That sounds bad in my opinion. A better way (which i couldnt figure out how to do) would be to load the data at the start, manipulate it while running (save it after each manipulate) and save it again when i close the script.

In my understandig of how (python) functions work, when they shall use informations from outside the function i need to give the function the information when i call it and when the function manipulate that informations and i wanna use it afterwards i need to return that informations. But how do i return that information when i call the function with a Button press with Tkinter? E.g.

```
import tkinter as tk
number = 1

def add():
    number += 1
    label.config(text=str(number))
    
def sub():
    number -= 1
    label.config(text=str(number))

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root,text=str(number))
button_add = tk.Button(root,text="+ 1",command=add)
button_sub = tk.Button(root,text="- 1",command=sub)

label.pack()
button_add.pack()
button_sub.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This script should increase or decreas a number and show it but it doesn't work because `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment`
Anyone who can explain this to me?

Edit:
I found out that this would work:

```
import tkinter as tk
number = [1]

def add():
    number[0] = number[0]+1
    label.config(text=str(number[0]))
    
def subtract():
    number[0] = number[0]-1
    label.config(text=str(number[0]))

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root,text=str(number[0]))
button_add = tk.Button(root,text="+ 1",command=add)
button_sub = tk.Button(root,text="- 1",command=subtract)

label.pack()
button_add.pack()
button_sub.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But i dont understand the differnce why i dont need to use global this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `number` cannot be reached inside your functions.
One way would be to use `global number` in both functions to make that variable availabe inside the function.

"When you are in a function and assign a value to a variable, it assumes it is in the local scope. using `global number` tells that function to look to the global scope as the reference of `number`."*

```
def add():
    global number
    number += 1
    label.config(text=str(number))


def sub():
    global number
    number -= 1
    label.config(text=str(number))
```

source*: [Python NameError, variable 'not defined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955081/python-nameerror-variable-not-defined)